# HTTP request from server or client - Best performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I was thinking about what would be the best performance, or if it is any difference at all. As an example; If you use a MEAN-stack, would it be better to use the HTTP request that Angular has, or is it better to request from server with Request.js or any similar?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you want to be sure then do a benchmark. I don't get how the content of your question relates to the title. In the title you ask if request from server or client is better, in the content you ask about Angular vs Request.js.

Comment: That does not matter at all, they are all the same thing.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I just gave an example, in case someone wouldn't understand what I meant.

Comment: I can't see an example.

Comment: "As an example; If you use A MEAN-stack, would it be ....". I was not talking about Request.js VS Angular, I was talking about request from server or client in general.

Answer (score 3):

**client-server** requests will be simplier & faster than **client-webServer-apiServer** requests definitely.

- If your application is complex and need to separate the web layer and API layer, then **client-webServer-apiServer** should be your choice.
- Otherwise, **client-server** architecture is just enough.

Answer (score 1):

If default things to make http request are meet your requirements, I don't see the reason to use any other libraries. But it doesn't matter really, you can use any way you really like.